# starting activity from tab fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to start an activity from a tab fragment and can not seem to get this to work! findviewbyid is highlighted in red and using intent to go from the fragment to the new activity is not working for me either! could someone help clear this up and show me how i would go from the fragment to a new activity! i have included the code where i am having trouble, thank you

```
public class tab2 extends Fragment {  
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2,container,false);

        return view;

        ImageButton pigsButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pigsButton);

        pigsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(tab2.this, pigs_story.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Any code after a `return` statement is unreachable

Comment: thank you, i did use getActivity() forgot to edit code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Use `view.findViewById();` and rearrange the return statement.

```
public class tab2 extends Fragment {  
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2,container,false);

        ImageButton pigsButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.pigsButton);

        pigsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(tab2.this, pigs_story.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you very much,, just solved a huge headache! how could not of noticed the return statement!!!

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is return the view just after it loads the desire layout , put your **return view** statement in last of your OnCreate function.

```
public class tab2 extends Fragment {  
        @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

           View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2,container,false);

           ImageButton pigsButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pigsButton);

                pigsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(tab2.this, pigs_story.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }
                });

                return view;
            }

        }
```